# Intertwining operators and induced representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, induced-representations

Let $G=GL(n, F)$, $B$ be a Borel subgroup and let $B=AN$ be the Langlands decomposition. Let $\nu \in \mathfrak{a}^*_{\mathbb{C}}$ be in the positive Weyl chamber. Consider the normalized induced representation $I = I^G_B(\nu)$. Let $F=\mathbb{R}$ and $J$ be the unique generic irreducible subrepresentation of $I$ which exists thanks to Theorem 6.2 for $F=\mathbb{R}$ of the article by Casselman-Shahidi titled "On irreducibility of standard modules for generic representations". It is known that the intertwining operator
$$
M(w_0) : I^G_B(\nu) \rightarrow I^G_{\bar{B}}(w_0(\nu)),
$$
corresponding to the longest Weyl group element annihilates every nonzero subrepresentation of $I^G_B(\nu)$. I was wondering if something more can be said here. For example

1. Is $J$ annihilated by all intertwining operators $M(w)$ where $w\in W$? I am mostly interested in the case of $\nu = \rho$ where $\rho$ is the half sum of positive roots.
2. In the same article the authors have proved analogue of Theorem 6.2 for nonarchimedean field and can be found as Theorem 1. What can we say about the analogue of the above theorem when $F$ is nonarchimedean field?
3. If more general results are known or expected in this direction, a reference would be much appreciated.

Any comments, suggestions or references are welcome. Please feel free to edit if you find something erroneous in the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer question 1 for when $\nu=\rho$ and $F$ is $p$-adic (since I am not too familiar with $F=\mathbb R$; I assume a similar argument works for $F=\mathbb R$ as well). It suffices to check that $I_B^G(\rho)$ is not isomorphic to $I_B^G(w\rho)$ for $w\ne1\in W$. But this is clear, since
$$\begin{align*}
\hom_G(I_B^G(\rho),1_G)&\cong\hom_G(1_G,I_B^G(-\rho))\\
&\cong\hom_G(1_G,\mathrm{Ind}_B^G(1_B))\\
&\cong\hom_B(1_B,1_B)\\
&\cong\mathbb C,
\end{align*}$$
where $\mathrm{Ind}_B^G$ denotes naive induction, but
$$\begin{align*}
\hom_G(I_B^G(w\rho),1_G)&\cong\hom_G(1_G,I_B^G(-w\rho))\\
&\cong\hom_G(1_G,\mathrm{Ind}_B^G(\rho-w\rho))\\
&\cong\hom_B(1_B,\rho-w\rho)\\
&=0,
\end{align*}$$
since $\rho\ne w\rho$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am confused about one point : Why do we know that the intertwining operator denoted by $M(w)$ (in the notation above) has nonzero kernel? Sorry if this is too obvious. I suppose you use it to conclude as follows : Since $M(w)$ has nonzero kernel and since the domain and target of $M(w)$ are not isomorphic (as shown by you), $J$ will necessarily be in the kernel of M(w).

Comment: Right, if $M(w)$ had no kernel, then we would obtain an injection $I_B^G(\rho)\hookrightarrow I_B^G(w\rho)$. Now, a dimension counting argument shows that the injection must be an isomorphism. Indeed, the invariants with respect to a sufficiently small compact open $K$ has dimension $|B\backslash G/K|$ on both sides.

Comment: Thank you very much.